# update multiple records by a single form which are fetched in a table

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Hi I'm not able to update multiple records which are fetching in a table using mysqli query , this is my code :

```
$count = 1;
if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0){
    while($roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $count. '</td>
            <td>' . $roww["enrolment"]. '</td>
            <td>' . $roww["student_name"]. '</td>
            <td>' . $roww["father_name"]. '</td>
            <td>' . $roww["email"]. '</td>
            <td> <input type="number" class ="form-control" min="2000" max="2099" value = '. $roww["rjit_year"] .'  > </td>
            <td> <input type="number" class ="form-control" min="2000" max="2099" value = '.$roww["rjit_end"].'  > </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" value = "0" '; if($roww["active"] == 0) echo "checked" ; echo '/></td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" value = "1" '; if($roww["active"] == 1) echo "checked" ; echo ' /></td>
        </tr>';
        $count++;
    }
}else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($db);
```

Here the `<td>' . $roww["enrolment"]. '</td>` is the unique value for evry user and he is able to edit the last four 's now literally dont have any idea how to do this.
This is the view of the html 
[image]

Comment: try to call update query on update button click and passed current id of field using jquery

Comment: need to done it will a single update button if it's 50 records or more

Comment: "UPDATE table_name SET column_name1=' value[$array]', column_name2=' value[$array]' WHERE column_name=' value[$array]' ";

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE table_name SET column_name1=' value[$array]', column_name2=' value[$array]' WHERE column_name=' value[$array]' ";
```

Comment: How do I set values in an array for enrolment since I'm not able to set name in <td> and how to run it an loop since there will be more than single value

Comment: try a for loop until length of records and or try this for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]', lastname='$lastname[$i]', email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}
}